# Forcing Stored Procedure to check before inserting data into table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I created this Stored Procedure,

Now what I want to do is, to always replace if a similiar type of record exists within table,

here's the sp,

```
USE [DBName]
GO

CREATE procedure [dbo].[InsertDD]
(
    @ColumnA varchar(1000), 
    @ColumnB varchar(1000),
    @CurrentDateAndTime datetime

)
AS

INSERT Into TableName
(
    ColumnA,    
    ColumnB,
    CurrentDateAndTime
)
Values
(
    @ColumnA,   
    @ColumnB,
    @CurrentDateAndTime
)
```

Now If table already has Column B  value (regardless of difference in letters e.g. capital or lower case) then just update `CurrentDateAndTime` value.

If not then simply add three of the values.

Comment: You tagged with `C#` this question because.. ?

Comment: If you want to update then what is stopping you from updating?

Comment: I don't know how to do that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the update, and if it didn't find any record to update, do the insert:

```
update TableName 
set CurrentDateAndTime = @CurrentDateAndTime
where ColumnB = @ColumnB

if (@@rowcount = 0) begin

  insert into TableName (
    ColumnA,    
    ColumnB,
    CurrentDateAndTime
  ) values (
    @ColumnA,   
    @ColumnB,
    @CurrentDateAndTime
  )

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a search for the IF ... EXISTS command. Ultimatily you can also use the MERGE statement, which determines using a SELECT if a row already exists and  you can do a UPDATE.